# Compile OpenGL application from Windows on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, g++

My friend made OpenGL graphic engine, but he is working on Windows. I want to compile project with it.
I installed all required libs with headers, but now problem is with linking (project in Code::Blocks). I found paths for `/usr/lib/libSOIL.a` and `/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a`, but what about:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libopengl32.a`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\assimp_debug-dll_win32\assimp.lib`

Also, what I must modify in project file to compile it? It requires: `glfw3, glm, gl3w.h, assimp, SOIL` (this is what I get from .hpp files). I installed all headers (downloaded sources and `make && make install`)...

I tried to compile it from terminal with g++, but I don't know switches for libraries.

Current situation:

> $ g++ Camera.o Entity.o Frustum.o gl3w.o Light.o Material.o Mesh.o Model.o ModelPart.o Shader.o Texture.o Utilities.o ../main.o -o main -L/usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a -lX11 -lXext -lXt -lSM -lGLU -lglut -lSOIL
>   /usr/bin/ld: gl3w.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glXGetProcAddress'
>   /usr/bin/ld: note: 'glXGetProcAddress' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/nvidia-313-updates/libGL.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-313-updates/libGL.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

(i added too much libraries to command line, I know)

**EDIT**
Added `-lGL` and `-ldl` and some problems comes out. Now, I'll trying compile it with makefile...

Comment: I think your problem is not about how to compile with OpenGL in Linux, but a general lack of understanding how the GCC build toolchain works in Linux. Just throwing a Makefile into that won't really solve that problem.

Comment: Now solved, just tons of mistakes with libraries etc. Also, Makefile is really better solution than C::B project...

Answer (score 1):

libopengl32 -> libGL.a

assimp -> libassimp.a ?

You gotta provide the Makefile you're compiling it with.

Comment: But from what directory? I have a few libGL.so, and none libassimp.a :( Please look at my edit, I added error from `ld`.

Comment: There is no libGL.a. You want to link to libGL.so simply by specifying the `-lGL` linker flag.

Comment: @aso you forgot to link with GLFW it seems, specify -lglfw3 to the commandline